# change content layout in facelets template by adding url parameter

Tags: url, jsf, primefaces, facelets

I have the following template file templateBase.xhtml:

```
<!--Normal SPA Layout-->
<c:if test="#{not MainActionBean.isLayoutTheme(param.theme)}">
<ui:insert name="pageHeader" />
<ui:insert name="content"/>
<ui:insert name="contentFooter"/>
</c:if> 

<!--3 panel layout-->
<c:if test="#{MainActionBean.isLayoutTheme(param.theme)}">
        <p:outputPanel id="templateBaseLayoutPanel" >
            <p:layout widgetVar="panelLayout">
                <p:layoutUnit position="west" id="westContentContainer">
                        <h:outputText value="Document List"  />
                        <ui:include src="/common/Documents.xhtml" />
                        <br/>
                        <h:outputText value="Action formulary"  />
                        <ui:insert name="actionSection"/>
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="center" id="centerContentContainer">
                            <ui:insert name="pageHeader" />
                            <ui:insert name="content"/>
                            <ui:insert name="contentFooter"/>
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="east" id="eastContentContainer">
East Panel Content
                </p:layoutUnit>
            </p:layout>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </c:if>
```

What I want to achieve is to change the current SPA layout to another with 3 columns when a given parameter with a specific value is added to the URL. In the SPA layout the "documents list" and "action formulary" are included into a subview in the "content" section of the template and in the 3 panel layout they should move to the west panel.  Currently after adding the param the layout units are being rendered but not the ui:insert and ui:include of the west panel. There are no errors on logs or console and rendition of components is controlled with method "MainActionBean.isLayoutTheme(param.theme)" to prevent ID duplication.

I'd like to know if what I'm trying is even possible or if there is a better approach for this.

P.S: I've tried to summarise and simplify the xhtml structure as much as possible, if needed will post the whole of it.

Comment: Does the p:layout render correctly without all that c:if and p:outputPanel (=deferred loading) stuff?

Comment: yes, the layoutUnits are all rendering but with nothing but the outputTexts inside them. The outputPanel in this case is just a placeholder not used at all.